# Alignment troubles with tabular, pgfuseimage and multirows

Tags: tikz-pgf, tables, multirow

I'm stuck with some alignment problems in tabular:
[image: my problem with pictures]

and in draft mode:

[image: my problem with just boxes]

The point is that the bottom left one should take the whole space without overflooding the bottom (so to speak)

The original MWE that gave these images is the following:

```
\documentclass[9pt,draft]{beamer}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{tikz}

\pgfdeclareimage[interpolate=true,height=.15\textheight]{mousse-hexa}{img/foam2D-honeycomb.png}
\pgfdeclareimage[interpolate=true,height=.15\textheight]{mousse-grain}{img/foam2D-grain-boundaries.png}
\pgfdeclareimage[interpolate=true,height=.15\textheight]{mousse-desor}{img/foam2D-disordered.png}
\pgfdeclareimage[interpolate=true,height=.15\textheight]{murissement}{img/foam2D-coarsening.png}
\pgfdeclareimage[interpolate=true,height=.30\textheight]{graphe-mur}{img/lauriesfoam.png}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{title}
\begin{tabular}{c l}
   \pgfuseimage{murissement}                 & \pgfuseimage{mousse-hexa}  \\
   \multirow{2}{*}{\pgfuseimage{graphe-mur}} & \pgfuseimage{mousse-grain} \\
                                             & \pgfuseimage{mousse-desor} \\
\end{tabular}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You could use the second optional argument of `\multirow` to shift your image up: For the draft version of your slide, `\multirow{2}{*}[0.1\textheight]{\pgfuseimage{graphe-mur}}` works quite well.

Comment: Thanks, it helps, visually. Still it was not the intended behaviour of multirow :/ And I don't know the exact shift value to make it look nice, and that feels not right...

Comment: Yeah, I agree. I'd be interested to see a proper solution to this, but I have the feeling that this is going to be quite hard.

Comment: As you noticed, this is a beamer presentation. Another workaround would be to use the `columns` environment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think a TiKZ matrix could help you. From you question I understand that you want to place
`lauriesfoam` horizontally aligned with south of `foam2D-disordered`. Next code shows how to do it with a TiKZ matrix. First a matrix with upper row a right most column is constructed and
after that, a node containing `lauriesfoam` figure is aligned with previous ones.
In left column last node is horizontally and vertically centered and right column shows previous option. With `calc` library help you can compute  more complex alignments.

```
\documentclass[9pt,draft]{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\pgfdeclareimage[interpolate=true,height=.15\textheight]{mousse-hexa}{img/foam2D-honeycomb.png}
\pgfdeclareimage[interpolate=true,height=.15\textheight]{mousse-grain}{img/foam2D-grain-boundaries.png}
\pgfdeclareimage[interpolate=true,height=.15\textheight]{mousse-desor}{img/foam2D-disordered.png}
\pgfdeclareimage[interpolate=true,height=.15\textheight]{murissement}{img/foam2D-coarsening.png}
\pgfdeclareimage[interpolate=true,height=.30\textheight]{graphe-mur}{img/lauriesfoam.png}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{title}
\begin{columns}[t]
\column{.5\textwidth}
\begin{tikzpicture}[ampersand replacement=\&]
\matrix[column sep=2mm,row sep=3mm]{
   \node[draw] (A11) {\pgfuseimage{murissement}};                 \& \node[draw] (A12) {\pgfuseimage{mousse-hexa}};  \\
    \& \node[draw] (A22) {\pgfuseimage{mousse-grain}}; \\ \& \node[draw] (A32) {\pgfuseimage{mousse-desor}}; \\
};
\path (A22.south) -- coordinate [midway] (C) (A32.north);
\fill (C) circle (2pt);
\node[draw] (D) at (A11|-C) {\pgfuseimage{graphe-mur}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\column{.5\textwidth}
\begin{tikzpicture}[ampersand replacement=\&]
\matrix[column sep=2mm,row sep=3mm]{
   \node[draw] (A11) {\pgfuseimage{murissement}};                 \& \node[draw] (A12) {\pgfuseimage{mousse-hexa}};  \\
    \& \node[draw] (A22) {\pgfuseimage{mousse-grain}}; \\ \& \node[draw] (A32) {\pgfuseimage{mousse-desor}}; \\
};
\path (A22.south) -- coordinate [midway] (C) (A32.north);
\fill (C) circle (2pt);
\node[draw,anchor=south] (D) at (A11|-A32.south) {\pgfuseimage{graphe-mur}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{columns}
 \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Nice :) I got something acceptable using columns in beamer. It is also much shorter to write and images width are controlled with column width.

Answer (score 3):

A simple solution is to lower the big image, pretending it has no height and depth with `\smash`:

```
\begin{frame}{title}
\begin{tabular}{c l}
\pgfuseimage{murissement} & \pgfuseimage{mousse-hexa}  \\
\smash{\raisebox{\dimexpr-.15\textheight-2pt\relax}{\pgfuseimage{graphe-mur}}}
                          & \pgfuseimage{mousse-grain} \\
                          & \pgfuseimage{mousse-desor} \\
\end{tabular}
\end{frame}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This seems too much over my head :) And I really prefer either using columns in beamer, or the accepted solution